# Input/Output Nodes - Specification and Description Language

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am new to TikZ. I am trying to create the below Input and Output nodes of Specification and Description Language

[image]

Is there an existing `\node` or `\tikzstyle` to achieve the above in the TikZ package?

Tried to read the below:

> http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf
> http://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

Seem not readily available.

TikZ shapes are extremely hard to create. I do not know if "chamfered rectangle" could be manipulated to get the two nodes.

Could you guide me on this.

**Update:**

Thanks to Sigur and Zarko.

`signal` is what I was been looking for. Implemented the below way and it worked like a charm. Consider this as solved.

```
\tikzstyle{output1} = [signal, signal from=nowhere, signal to=east,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black,
fill=blue!30]
 
\tikzstyle{input1} = [signal, signal from=east, signal to=nowhere,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black,
fill=red!30]
```

Comment: See TikZ manual, pp.703 -- 704 'shape signal'.

Comment: Pg 721, 722 on V3.0.0.

Comment: Well, I look in CVS version from July 18. There signal shape is in mentioned pages. In CTAN version seems to be as Sigur mention .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the OP with reference to the comments given.